# How to make button hovering to stay on button when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, angular

I have 3 buttons:

```
<div>
  <button md-button
          (click)="setButtonIndex(0)"
          class="md-primary">Button1
  </button>

  <button md-button
          (click)="setButtonIndex(1)"
          class="md-primary">Button2
  </button>

  <button md-button
          (click)="setButtonIndex(2)"
          class="md-primary">Button3
  </button>
</div>
```

it looks like this:

[image]

note that the different bg on the button is when hovering, but I want that to stay when someone clicks on the button...

thanks

Comment: You've already asked this question. Please delete this question and reply on the question asked at the other one

Comment: @NewToJS I havent, I dont know what to try

Comment: try to add a different css class containing a new background via jquery

Comment: The usual technique is to have a class with a name like "active" or "current", and when a button is clicked add the class to it and remove the class from the button that *was* current.

Comment: @nnnnnn OP already asked this in another question, so hopefully you can close this one

Comment: @LGSon the other question was not asked properly so I decided to create new one.

Comment: Then you edit it, not post a new

Comment: @LGSon and the other question was specificy for adding underline under a button

Comment: Its the same logic

Comment: Jack - Whether you are adding underlining or background colour or changing the font size or whatever, the normal practice is to do so via CSS classes as per my previous comment. I have no idea how you'd do that in Angular2 (I don't use Angular), but I'm sure the detail of underline versus background colour is irrelevant.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks buddy